# Are any verbs conjugated the same in preterit and present tenses?

Tags: verbos, conjugación

Am I correct that some present tense are the same conjugation in preterit tense?

For instance, "hablamos".

Or "hablo" is another example.

How do you tell the difference?

Comment: 'Hablo' does not fit your criteria.

Comment: @Paul yes it does.

Comment: @VladimirNul: the accent makes a big difference.

Comment: *hablamos* doesn't have an acute.

Answer (score 10):

In the indicative mood **hablamos** is both present and past and is the rest of the sentence that tells you the time.

> Nosotros hablamos del partido = We talk about the game.
>
> Ayer hablamos del partido = We talked yesterday about the game.

The situation with **hablo** is different because **hablo** is present of the first person and **habló** is past of the third (notice the accent mark):

> Yo hablo del partido = I talk about the game.
>
> Él habló del partido = He talked about the game.

The indicative present and past conjugation of the verb **hablar** are as follows:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+
|            |   Present    |     Past     |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| - Yo       | hablo        | hablé        |
| - Tú       | hablas       | hablaste     |
| - Él       | habla        | habló        |
| - Nosotros | hablamos     | hablamos     |
| - Vosotros | habláis      | hablasteis   |
| - Ellos    | hablan       | hablaron     |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

There is also an imperfect form but you can check it out [here](http://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/hablar).

Comment: @Roddy Since you're new here, note you can mark an answer accepted if your question is already solved. You can do it clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. See [Help Center > Asking](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if you have any question!

Answer (score 5):

Any regular verb of the first conjugation (verbs with infinitive ending in 'ar') have this condition for the first plural person: **jugamos, bailamos, rezamos**... in fact just now I can't think of irregular verbs that doesn't meet the condition.

In the third conjugation (verbs ending in 'ir') it happens too, like in **dormimos, discutimos, salimos, reímos**. An exception can be found in **vamos/fuimos**.

We tell the difference just by the context: in common uses is really simple, however, in poetry or some obscure texts it can lead to confusion.

Comment: The point with _ir_ is that it's an irregular verb. I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: You can't think of irregular verbs that does *not* meet the condition?